# How to get the 'top most' data

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I want to get the 'top most' data from a table similar:

```
A B C | Id
1 2 3 | 1
  4 5 | 1
    6 | 1
```

A-C=Columns
1-6 values (field not set are empty)
Data is in descending order according to it's id in sequence

When I query I want to get the latest written data, in this example the query should give me 1, 4 and 6 in a single row:

```
a b c | Id
1 4 6 | 1
```

This is what I've tried but then I get the correct result but in different rows:

```
select * from
( select id, a from dataTable where id=(select max(dt.dataRow) from dataTable dt where dt.id = 1)) a_query
full outer join
( select id, b from dataTable where id=(select max(dt.dataRow) from dataTable dt where dt.id = 1)) b_query
on a_query.id=b_query.id 
full outer join
( select id, c from dataTable where id=(select max(dt.dataRow) from dataTable dt where dt.id = 1)) c_query 
on nvl(a_query.id, b_query.id)=c_query.id
```

Preferable Oracle SQL

Answer (score 3):

That seems overly complex, just get the max of each column (and use COALESCE in case of null values for the column):

```
SELECT [id], MAX(COALESCE(a, 0)) AS a, 
    MAX(COALESCE(b, 0)) AS b, 
    MAX(COALESCE(c, 0)) AS c
FROM dataTable 
GROUP BY [id]
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, although I still get excessive rows with this solution and data I want is spread between these two rows.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "excessive rows" or the data is spread between two rows?  Showing your schema with more specific examples would be helpful.

Comment: if you have more than one "id" then you'll have more than 1 row but it makes sense... Results are grouped by Id

Answer (score 0):

I might have simplified my example a little to much. The data in A,B,C might be non-numeric and not sorted and so forth.

I found last_value() http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-nov/o66asktom-099001.html fit very well with this which would return:

```
A B C | Id
1 2 3 | 1
1 4 5 | 1
1 4 6 | 1
```

for me to operate furhter on.

Then the query looks something like this:

```
select distinct 
last_value(a ignore nulls) over (order by id) a,
last_value(b ignore nulls) over (order by id) b,
last_value(c ignore nulls) over (order by id) c
from datatable
where datatable.id IN (select id from datatable where datatable.id = 1)
```